# Manage a block of configuration in file

Tags: ansible

I'm a beginner in Ansible and I'm looking to manage configuration blocks in my configuration files.

I try to add a configuration block when it is not present in my file but the solution I found does not work as I would like

Indeed, if the block is already present but is different from a space for example, Ansible will add the block at the end of the file so there will be twice the configuration block

Here are my different files (configuration file, playbook,...)

***current configuration file with configuration block and additional spaces:***

```
# Example of configuration file
#
############################################################
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Aliquam tempor tortor et sodales suscipit. 
# Nulla a turpis vel purus ultricies sodales a quis est.
# Maecenas tincidunt nunc et ex tincidunt dictum.
############################################################
# Block of conf
Here is
My Block
of conf
```

***extract of my playbook:***

```
- name: Get conf block of file
  shell: cat /my/conf/file.cfg | grep -a2 "of conf"
  register: conf_host
  failed_when: "conf_host.rc == 2" # Avoid error when grep return is empty

- name: Check conf block
  blockinfile:
    path: /my/conf/file.cfg
    marker: "<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->"
    block: |
      # Block of conf
      Here is
      My Block
      of conf
    when: conf_host.stdout != expected_conf
    vars:
      expected_conf: |-
        Here is
        My Block
        of conf
```

***result due to excess space:***

```
# Example of configuration file
#
############################################################
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Aliquam tempor tortor et sodales suscipit. 
# Nulla a turpis vel purus ultricies sodales a quis est.
# Maecenas tincidunt nunc et ex tincidunt dictum.
############################################################
# Block of conf
Here is
My Block
of conf  
<!-- START ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->
# Block of conf
Here is
My Block
of conf
<!-- END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->
```

***expected result:***

```
# Example of configuration file
#
############################################################
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Aliquam tempor tortor et sodales suscipit. 
# Nulla a turpis vel purus ultricies sodales a quis est.
# Maecenas tincidunt nunc et ex tincidunt dictum.
############################################################
# Block of conf
Here is
My Block
of conf
```

***or:***

```
# Example of configuration file
#
############################################################
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
# Aliquam tempor tortor et sodales suscipit. 
# Nulla a turpis vel purus ultricies sodales a quis est.
# Maecenas tincidunt nunc et ex tincidunt dictum.
############################################################
<!-- START ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->
# Block of conf
Here is
My Block
of conf
<!-- END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->
```

I don't know if my request is understandable or if you have a better solution.

Thanks

KR

Answer (score 1):

You should use ansible jinja module. Jinja will basically create a configuration file for you based on certain parameters.

Jinja template module supports loops as well

Usage of template module:

```
template:
  src: configuration.j2
  dest: <path>/configuration
```

configuration.j2 will hold all your file content

Comment: Indeed, the use of modules could perhaps help me but I prefer to try without them at first. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `failed_when: "conf_host.rc == 2"`, change it to `ignore_errors: true` to continue executing ansible playbook and change the when condition to have `conf_host.stdout == ""` to update the file.

Below is the modified code. I have tried it locally and it works.

```
- name: Get conf block of file
  shell: cat /my/conf/file.cfg | grep -a2 "of conf"
  register: conf_host
  ignore_errors: true # Ignore when grep return is empty

- name: Check conf block
  blockinfile:
    path: /my/conf/file.cfg
    marker: "<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->"
    block: |
      # Block of conf
      Here is
      My Block
      of conf
    when: conf_host.stdout == ""
    vars:
      expected_conf: |-
        Here is
        My Block
        of conf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this configuration, I check if the 3 grep lines are present except that if one of these three lines has a modification other than a space, I am no longer able to check it.
I don't know if you know what I mean.
Example :
`# Block of conf`
`Here is`
`My bad Block`
`of conf`

This configuration will be considered as good by Ansible because the grep is not empty